# simplepeer.js is not working on mobile browser in android

Tags: browser, webrtc, p2p, peer

I am using simplepeer.js with pusher api and I have developed an audio/video calling system but there is a problem that it is not working on the mobile browser chrome/firefox.

I have tested my system on Mozilla and chrome on laptop ,it is working fine on both but on the mobile when I call the person ,peer stream starts and then it close suddenly.

Can anyone help me about this issue?